# closing words for e-mail to person with incurable disease

Tags: expressions, formality, business-language

What kind of closing words as an alternative to

> We wish you full and quick recovery

can be used in a formal letter when writing to a person with an **incurable disease**.

---

> I/We wish you all the best for a good and efficient treatment so that you can continue your personal and private projects for a long time

Is something like this appropriate?

Thanks, B.

Comment: How about 'I hope you have a quick and easy recovery'. or 'I hope you have an easy recovery and a full life ahead'? Personally, I find the usage of private and personal project awkward in this context

Comment: This is not an answer, but I would prefer something short and simple, to show your empathy and understanding, but try to remain positive but not dwell on the details of the treatment or affliction.

Comment: @zen I think the question was because OP knows the affliction is incurable. If you've been told that it is an incurable disease, then probably better to avoid mentioning "recovery" as it may come across like you're being dense or something.

Comment: @Brandin, you are right, "recovery" might even come across as insensitive.

Comment: This somewhat depends on what the rest of the message was.  Is the disease actually discussed in the body of the message?  If not, it is probably best not to refer to it implicitly in any manner.  "Our thoughts are with you." is true, simple, straightforward, and unobjectionable.

Comment: A lot may depend on how well you know the person and their state of mind about the illness. For some I have known one could get away with saying *Very best in your continued efforts to prove the doctors wrong, and that you go to all their funerals*. A bit of humour works in some cases. But be careful - it is not always the right approach.

Answer (score 3):

My advice for determining what the appropriate closing lines should be is to reverse the situation, and imagine that you are the person with the terminal illness (assuming that "terminal illness" is what you mean by "incurable disease") and that the person you are writing to is instead writing to you. Now, what would you think appropriate for that person to say to you, and what would you like that person to say?

If your relationship is formal and not particularly close, you might not want the person to say much in closing beyond "Best wishes." If your relationship is work-related but strong and genuinely warm, you might like to hear something like "I think of you often and am grateful for your friendship and for the opportunity to have worked with you and learned from you. Thank you for being such a positive force in so many people's lives."

If I were the terminally ill person, I would be touched by a sincerely expressed appreciation, but I would have little patience for artifice whether in the form of false optimism or of false intimacy. Life is too short for that kind of stuff. You know your relationship with the dying person, so you are in the best position to gauge the nature and extent of your feelings for each other. Use that knowledge honestly and judiciously, and you can't go far wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I find your alternative a bit too long for an ending message.

---

Is something like

> We wish you good continuation and warmest regards.

fits you?

It is a solution where you don't talk about the forced treatment.

---

If you want to talk about the treatment, what about :

> We wish this treatment will ease your pain and the success in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to close a communication expressing this kind of sentiment without reference to any deity or religious process, or have to be sensitive to some condition it would be impolite or insensitive to reference, I use:

> Wishing you peace and love

or

> Wishing you love and light

or some other combination of generic *nice things* of a neutral nature

EDIT: Oops, I have just noticed the OP mentions a formal communication- neither of these could really be considered for a formal letter. I would just go with

> Best Regards

or something equally formal but neutral such as the standard

> Yours Sincerely

Comment: Your suggestions sound a bit too close to the sorts of things one says about the dead to use in the circumstances.

Comment: "Have a wonderful afterlife, Yours Sincerely, Mum"?